# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username' in django 

Tags: django

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'
 This is the error I get . 
I have gone through most of the questions related to it and did some changes accordingly . But didn't meet with the solution yet . 
In my settings.py this is there

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ( "django.core.context_processors.debug", "django.core.context_processors.i18n")
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
     'django.core.context_processors.request',
     'django.core.context_processors.debug',
 'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
     'django.core.context_processors.media',
     'django.core.context_processors.static',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

) 
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "prof.userprofile"
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
)
```

I want to know what does this error mean , as this is the first time I have come across such an error . And how to debug it ?
Edit:

```
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'
Exception Location: /home/satyajit/geodjango/geographic_admin/prof/views.py in view_foo, line 18
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.gis.shortcuts import render_to_kml

from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required




@login_required 
def view_foo(request):

   user1 = User.objects.get(user=request.User.username)
   return render_to_response('welcome.html', {})
```

Comment: My crystal ball broke, you'll need to show us the location of the error and the code that raises it.

Comment: Full tracebacks are often the most helpful.  Barring that, I'm guessing you're doing `request.username` in a view somewhere, where you really want `request.user.username`.

Comment: I have put the place where the error has opened .

Comment: still not enough context, seem like you used: "request.username" and wanted: "request.user.username"

Comment: @mekasperasky, see the second half of my first comment.

Comment: I did user.username . Its saying user field doesnt exist .

Comment: I have edited my question and have put the views and the proper traceback

Comment: You might want to post line 18 of `views.py`, also, plus maybe the initial definition line of `view_foo()`.

Comment: Have put up the whole views.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: ok I just realized how silly this query is and my mistake :D.

If you want the username, you could do something like this:

```
user1= request.user.username
```

you get the user instance by `request.user`.

```
this_user = request.user
```

A little explanation: your initial query does not make much sense, because the User class does not have the field user. Also, this query is superfluous because the user instance is already provided by the request (request.user, which is the user whose session

Comment: I did that . It says can not resolve the keyword user . Choices are username , fname , lname ..

Comment: Sir you are a saviour .   this_user = request.user
   user1= this_user.username
  
   return render_to_response('welcome.html', {'user':user1}) This is what I did .

Comment: But . But . The welcome.html doesn't display the user . Hmmph . I have done {{user.username}} in the template

Comment: that's because user1 is a string with the value of user.username, but you need user1 to be an User instance, so try this: user1=request.user, should work in the template just fine

Comment: Fixed it . Even I realized what a silly error that was . Thank you SO MUCH

Comment: I will be happy if you can explain , what exactly was the error at the beginning and how did your instantiation fixed it

Answer (score 5):

Errors (and their tracebacks) in python are almost always helpful, and rarely contain irrelevant information.

`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'`.  `WSGIRequest` is the class of requests that come in from WSGI requests from the webserver.  The convention is to handle these in views as the "request" parameter.  So the error indicates that you are doing `request.bad_attribute` somewhere, where `bad_attribute` in this case is `username`.

Your request would only have an attribute named `username` if some middleware were active that added it.  However, the defaults in django include middleware that adds a `user` object, so that's probably what you really wanted.  `request.user.username`.

Also, remember that attribute access is case-sensitive.  It is, after all, Just Python.

Comment: I did exactly that sir . But got an error saying that it can not resolve the keyword user .

Comment: @mekasperasky your edit indicates that you are accessing `request.User`.  `request` has no attribute `User`, but it should have an attribute `user` (lower case).  If not, did you change the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting?  You might be missing the middleware that adds that.

Comment: I have submitted my middleware_classes settings here . It is the same . No changes .

Comment: @mekasperasky and you've fixed the case-sensitivity issue?